# Calling map::find with a const argument

Tags: c++, constants

I have an object:

```
map<A*, string> collection;
```

I would like to call the map::find function, but the value I have for the key is const, like in the following code, which does not compile:

```
const A* a = whatever();
collection.find(a);
```

The following code works and performs the equivalent of the find operation:

```
const A* a = whatever();
map<A*, string>::iterator iter;
for(iter = collection.begin(); iter != collection.end(); ++iter)
    if(iter->first == a)
        break;
// iter now contains the result or map::end (just like map::find)
```

But it is probably not as efficient as the find member function, and it's also ugly and masks the intent of the code.

How can I call the find function?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am intentionally using a pointer type for the key in the map. The behaviour I want is for the map to use pointer equality for the keys. (Just like in my loop code)

Comment: What compilation error do you get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comparing pointers has nothing to do with it. The OP may or may not need a custom compare operation; it looks to me like they're just looking for a specific object by its address, which seems perfectly reasonable. The first two answers seem to have missed the point that find() doesn't compile while a handwritten search works.

The `find()` call won't compile because you're passing it the wrong type to search for. `map::find()` expects its argument to be the same type as the map's key type, which is `A*`. You're passing a `const A*`, which is not implicitly convertible to an `A*` (but is comparable to an `A*`, which is why the handwritten search works). The implicit conversion only works in the other direction (`A*` to `const A*`, not `const A*` to `A*`).

Possibly you should be using `const A*` instead of `A*` as the map key; depending on what you're using the map for, this may or may not be practical. If you need the map key to be `A*`, you need to pass an `A*` to `find()`, which means either starting with an `A*` as your search target in the first place, or if you can only get it from its original source as a `const A*`, using `find(const_cast<A*>(a))` to turn it into a pointer to non-const (which is not the same as a non-const pointer, a point that confuses a lot of C/C++ coders). Usually `const_cast` is inadvisable, but here it's safe since you're only comparing the pointer, not dereferencing it.

Comment: Yes, this is an accurate expanded description of my problem. It seems that using a const_cast is the only way to go, but it's frustrating that no cast is needed with the "handwritten search". I am almost tempted to just use the handwritten search, since I hate casts. Could the original library find function have been written to work in this scenario, or is there a limitation in the C++ language?

Comment: The big advantage of map::find() over a simple linear search is that it's much faster if the collection is large.

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove the const

```
const A* a = whatever();
collection.find( const_cast<A*>(a) );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I am hoping there is a way without using a cast

Comment: @bartsimpson - You could modify your map to contain `const A*`