# const_cast issue with std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

I recently hit a problem and the only way I can see to avoid it is to use const_cast - but I'm guessing there is a way I'm not thinking of to avoid this without otherwise changing the function of the code.  The code snippet below distills my problem into a very simple  example.

```
struct Nu
{
    Nu() {v = rand();}
    int v;
};

struct G
{
    ~G()
    {
        for(auto it = _m.begin(); it != _m.end(); it++) delete it->first;
    }
    void AddNewNu()
    {
        _m[new Nu] = 0.5f;
    }
    void ModifyAllNu()
    {
        for(auto it = _m.begin(); it != _m.end(); it++) it->first->v++;
    }
    float F(const Nu *n) const
    {
        auto it = _m.find(n);
        // maybe do other stuff with it
        return it->second;
    }

    map<Nu*, float> _m;
};
```

Here, suppose Nu is actually a very large struct whose layout is already fixed by the need to match an external library (and thus the "float" can't simply be folded into Nu, and for various other reasons it can't be `map<Nu, float>`). The G struct has a map that it uses to hold all the Nu's it creates (and ultimately to delete them all on destruction). As written, the function F will not compile - it cannot cast (const Nu *n) to (Nu *n) as expected by std::map. However, the map can't be switched to `map<const Nu*, float>` because some non-const functions still need to modify the Nu's inside _m.  Of course, I could alternatively store all these Nu*'s in an additional std::vector and then switch the map type to be const - but this introduces a vector that should be entirely unnecessary.  So the only alternative I've thought of at the moment is to use const_cast inside the F function (which should be a safe const_cast) and I'm wondering if this is avoidable.

After a bit more hunting this exact same problem has already been addressed here: [Calling map::find with a const argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817910/calling-mapfind-with-a-const-argument)

Comment: Either my C++ knowledge is bad or your variable declarations make no sense to me. What is the keyword "auto" doing there?

Comment: If "some non-const functions still need to modify the Nu's inside _m", Nu cannot be used as a map key. Once it's modified, map is no longer ordered.

Comment: @Joris, `auto` is a new feature of C++0x - maybe some compilers already support it?

Comment: @Joris: `auto` in C++0x is used to infer type of variable from its initializer.

Comment: There are quite a few unclear things in your question. How is your map ordered? According to the declaration you provided `map<Nu*, float> _m;` you are not using any custom comparator with your map, which means that your map will compare the pointer values for ordering. Is this your intent? Or are you intending to compare the actual `Nu` objects to establish ordering? In the latter case, there is a danger of breaking the ordering in the map every time you perform the outside modification of any `Nu` object.

Comment: A map of pointers is not ordered in any sensible way, unless you include a comparison functor in the definition. By default it sorts by pointer value.

Comment: The intent was to compare the pointer values for ordering.

Comment: OK, I understand - the intent is to have an associative container that essentially connects an additional piece of information to an existing object. OK to index by pointer value in that case because you don't care about order.

Comment: @Matt: Why not just use composition? `struct MyNu { Nu n; float f; };`. Or you could even inherit, if you wanted pointer conversions.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, `std::less` is well-defined for pointers, and it's fine to make a map of pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling map::find with a const argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817910/calling-mapfind-with-a-const-argument)

Comment: Since you are right and it really is the same question, I voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `map` expects `Nu* const`, but you have given it a `const Nu*`. I also find it highly illogical and don't understand why, but this is how it is.

Answer (score -1):

"find" in your case will return a const_iterator. putting:

```
map<Nu*,float>::const_iterator it = _m.find(n);

...

return it->second;
```

should work I think.

Since you are in a const method you can only read your map of course, not write/modify it

Comment: Unfortunately this won't compile either -- the return type will be inferred correctly as map<Nu*,float>::const_iterator, but .find(n) won't match the parameters because it can't cast the const Nu* to Nu*.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Just put the code in a cpp file here to mess around with it.